# draw multiple polylines on map with different colors

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a JSON array with multiple routes of latitudes and longitudes. It looks like the following:

My requirement is to draw each journey on the map using different colors, but my script draws all the journeys in one color:

The code used is:

```
<script>
        function initialize() {
          var jsonValues = '<?php echo $json; ?>';
          var oJsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonValues);

          console.log(oJsonObj);
          var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.932088333333334, 79.84256166666667),
                };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              mapOptions);

          Object.size = function(obj) {
                var size = 0, key;
                for (key in obj) {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
                }
                return size;
          };

          var numJournies = Object.size(oJsonObj);
          var journey = [];

          $.each(oJsonObj, function(ind,val){

             var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
             var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
             var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
             color= "rgb("+r+" ,"+g+","+ b+")"; 


            var journey = [];
             $.each(val, function(i,v){
                journey.push(new google.maps.LatLng(v.latitude, v.longitude));

             });


             polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: journey,
                    strokeColor: color,
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 3
                });

             polyline.setMap(map);


          });


        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: It looks like follows: {"154":[{"latitude":"6.8936150000000005","longitude":"79.85428"},{"latitude":"6.8936150000000005","longitude":"79.85428"}]},
{"155":[{"latitude":"6.8936150000000005","longitude":"79.85428"}]}

Comment: please update your question.  Code in comments is not particularly useful.

Comment: The JSON you provided contains 3 points, all at the same location.

Answer (score 0):

Take one Array With Different colors.

```
var Colors = ["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF", "#FFFFFF", "#000000", "#FFFF00", "#00FFFF", "#FF00FF"];
```

Now, instead of drawing one polyline, draw a separate polyline for each coordinate.

```
for (var i = 0; i < DrivePath.length-1; i++) {
  var PathStyle = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [DrivePath[i], DrivePath[i+1]],
    strokeColor: Colors[i],
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    map: map
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it still draws only one line. Do you have a demo url of ure implementation?

Comment: Please try to implement in same manner it will sure work, as i don't have any demo link for this as it's a logic that should work.